# Dynamic placeholder height

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a list with a `position: fixed` button in the bottom of the viewport. Because this button is `position: fixed` the last element of the list and part of the second last appear beneath the button, so the user can't see them properly.

What I tried so far:

- adding a `padding-bottom` to the container with the height of the button. Issue with this approach: in different languages the height of the button is different, so it's good in only a couple of scenarios.
- making the button `position: sticky` instead of fixed. Issue with this approach: the list is in a `overflow-y: scroll` container, so this approach does not work in iOS. Again, only good in a couple of scenarios.
- adding a div after the list and controlling its height with javascript. Issue with this approach: does the job, but it's not very elegant.

Does anyone know of a better approach other than my third one? When I started with this I thought I might have to use JS for it, but `position: sticky` gave me hope that it would be possible with only CSS.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is fixed, this is an example of what I do for buttons on the bottom of my screen. *Although it would be nice if you showed an example of your problem, cause it's hard to tell.*

Obviously, you'll have to edit the text's positioning if you wanted, but the principle is what matters, and everything is responsive. Each individual `<li>` element is 10% high and 20% wide no matter the size of the screen.

**CSS:**

```
<style>
  ul { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 10%; bottom: 0%; left: 0%; background-color: deepskyblue; list-style-type: none; margin: 0; }
  li { position: absolute; }
  .a { width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: red; left: 0%; }
  .b { width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: orange; left: 20%; }
  .c { width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: yellow; left: 40%; }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">AAA</li>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="c">CCC</li>
</ul>
```